# How to calculate toal in girdview in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have `Product` table item qty rate total if i insert qty into template field of qty that time `qty * rate` and total will display to 'total column'. say qty template textbox name is `txtqty`. I want calculation on `txtqty_change event`

My item and rate coming from table.

Thanks

Nandan Navale

Comment: what you want to calculate?

Comment: I propose you to point, where (List, HashTable, Array) do you store array of your values?

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to look for the sum function. Here goes good description http://www.dotnetperls.com/sum. For example, if you have List of Product lst, and Product has field Qty, you can use the following:

```
private void txtqty_change event()
{
    double summ = lst.Sum(a => a.Qty);
}
```